# Which Canoe version be compatible with soln provided for REDIS client implementation in the link https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis

Tags: redis, servicestack, .net-framework-version, servicestack.redis, canoe

I have imported the implementation of REDIS client from the link https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis. This is an implementation in c#.
Visual Studio Version : 2017
Target Framework : .NET Framework 4.6.1
ServiceStack.Redis.Core : 5.11.0
Using the above toolchain and implementation, I am able to send command to REDIS server from .NET application.

Next step is to integrate the .net implementation as a simulation node in CANOE.
CANOE Version : 11.0.96(Sp4)

When I try to include the solution in CANOE, I get the below error and warnings:
What I understand is that there is a version compatibility issue. Which version of CANOE would be compatible or what steps should I follow next?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Starting from CANoe 13.0, the .NET framework 4.7 is supported.
Check the following option in CANoe 13.0

- Go to CANoe options
- Under "Programming", go to ".NET"
- Select ".NET 4.7" as the Target Framework

I hope this solves your requirement.